# Custom loop won't work, can't find problem

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I can't figure out why this custom loop isn't displaying for me:. I've tried removing the if statement and removing certain query parameters but it just won't display. If I delete the loop entirely the page displays the layout, so I know it's the loop itself, I just can't find the problem.

Anyone with a sharp eye notice what I've done wrong?

```
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'showposts' => 10 ,
        'meta_key' => 'event_datestart',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value' ,
        'order' => 'ASC' ,
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
<?php 
    $raweventstart = get_field('event_datestart');
    $raweventend = get_field('event_dateend');

    $eventstart = strtotime("$raweventstart");
    $eventend = strtotime ("$raweventend");
    $now = strtotime("now"); 

    //Check if event is in the future or past.

    if ($eventstart >= $now) {
?>

                <div class="main-area-section-content">

                <div class="event-wrapper">
                        <div class="event-header">
                            <div class="event-date">
                            <?php echo $raweventstart; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="venue-name">
                            <?php if (get_field ('venue_name') ) { the_field('venue_name'); } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="event-content">
                            <div class="event-address">
                            <?php if (get_field ('venue_address') ) { the_field('venue_address'); } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="venue-phone">
                            <?php if (get_field ('venue_phone') ) { the_field('venue_phone'); } ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="venue-website">
                            <?php if (get_field ('venue_website') ) { ?><a href="<?php echo get_field('venue_website'); } ?>">Venue Website</a> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-description">
                            <?php if (get_field ('event_description') ) { the_field('event_description'); } ?> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            <?php } //end check to see if event is in the past?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't believe that `get_field` is a core function, is it?

Comment: @vancoder It's from ACF. As for finding out what's breaking it, try setting WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php

Comment: well first of all, one should *never* use `query_posts`. second, I suggest checking out `WP_Query`'s `meta_query` to query for posts based on date, rather than filtering them after the query.

Comment: Have you checked if `$raweventstart` is even populated in your loop?

Comment: Thanks @milo, you're right I shouldn't have been using query_posts. Below is this simplified verson that works using WP_query.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thanks to advice from above (this is a simplified version):

```
    $args = array('post_type' => 'event');
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```